# std::shared_ptr deleted in a getter function with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr

I'm using shared pointers for my Qt project, but when I call `setLayout()` through a shared pointer I get a segmentation fault.

I'm calling it like this:

```
 model->getBody()->setLayout(layoutTemplate.get());
```

The function `getBody()` returns a `std::shared_ptr`:

```
std::shared_ptr<QWidget> MainTemplate::getBody()
{
   return std::shared_ptr<QWidget>(ui->body);
}
```

I tried using `QSharedPointer` instead of `std::shared_ptr`, but that gave me the same result.

**Why is my pointer deleted?**

Comment: Since the `shared_ptr` only lives until the end of that statement the next time you try to use `ui->body` it will have been deleted.

Comment: Thanks, so I cannot return a shared_ptr with a getter?

Comment: Why do you need a `shared_ptr` there?

Comment: I don't know, it's a request from my supervisor.

Comment: Why do you use smart pointers with QObjects with parents? You do know that parent QObject deletes all its children when it is destructed?

Comment: This pointer is created by the UI so I cannot change its type. Yes, I know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart pointers represent *ownership* of objects. `shared_ptr` in particular represents an object that is owned by multiple entities and has to live until everyone is done using it. Whenever the last `shared_ptr` pointing to an object is destroyed, the object it points to is also destroyed. The proper use of `shared_ptr` is:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr_a(new T); // Create a T and immediately pass it to shared_ptr
std::shared_ptr<T> ptr_b = std::make_shared<T>(); // Same effect but more efficient

ptr_a = ptr_b; // smart pointer to smart pointer assignment (never existing raw to smart)
ptr_a.reset(new T);            // This is fine.
ptr_a = std::make_shared<T>(); // Same as previous line. Again more efficient

//... eventually ptr_a and ptr_b go out of scope and handle deleting their objects
```

Note that in all the examples of reassignment, `ptr_a` checked the reference count and deleted the held object if it was the last `shared_ptr` pointing to it.

Generally, you only ever want to pass raw pointers to smart pointers at the exact moment of their creation. What you did is pass *ownership* of an object to a temporary smart pointer. After the statement, the temporary `shared_ptr` was destroyed and as no copy of it was ever made, it assumed it should destroy `ui->body`. Generally what you want to do is simply return `body` by non-const reference, or just not return it and provide setter functions for its parameters.

```
QWidget& MainTemplate::getBody()
{
   return ui->body;
}
```

If however, some reason dictates that body needs to be able to outlive its class (doubtful, unless questionable design decisions have been made), you need to make body itself a `shared_ptr` and return it by value. This will create copies of `shared_ptr` and you are guaranteed that the last one of them will destroy the object. But you must NEVER use the raw pointer after body's construction and you must not manually try to delete it.

```
UI {    // whatever class MainTemplate::ui points to
private:
    std::shared_ptr<<QWidget> body;
...
}

MainTemplate {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<QWidget> MainTemplate::getBody()
    {
        return ui->body;
    }
}
```

Again, I don't think this is needed if your classes have been defined in a practical way. Also, you could make `ui` a `shared_ptr` if it does not belong to a class, and return that instead of its body. Then, let the caller access body through a returned `shared_ptr<UI>`.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the shared_ptr only lives until the end of that statement<sup>1</sup> the next time you try to use ui->body it will have been deleted.

You probably don't want to create a new shared ownership in a getter. Instead whatever is being gotten should exist as a shared_ptr, and the getter can return a copy (of the shared_ptr).

Alternatively, in the case where you are not transferring ownership, a raw pointer (where body can be null) or a reference (where body must not be null) is more appropriate. The usual caveats of pointers/references not outliving the pointed/referenced objects still apply.

1. And no copies of it have been made